# npm install throwing errors

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

The code throws the same error when `npm install` or `npm install --save` is called.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/andyc/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/andyc/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/andyc/.npm/_logs/2021-11-04T02_19_18_554Z-debug.log
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: There is no package. json file in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have package.json. So, you need to follow these steps, for every new project

Step: 1

```
npm init --yes
```

Step: 2

```
npm i --save 'packagename'
```

Step: 3 - When you delete and re-install packages by deleting node_modules, run this:

```
npm i/install
```